# PHP - Is it possible to create folder based on referer / previous page url?

Tags: php, referer, create-directory

I'm trying to write a code which would create folder based on referer - url which was form submitted from. Something like this:

```
if( !is_dir($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '/gallery/') ) {
    mkdir($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '/gallery/', 0750, true );
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The hash wouldn't be visible by your PHP script, as the browser does not send it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know, I'll remove that from my question.

Comment: And what is not working with your script? Have you tested it with debugging enabled?

Comment: It does not work for me, the thing is, referer's url is created dynamically, so that directory doesn't exist.

Comment: try removing special chars like ":"

Comment: 2ndkauboy makes a good point with his answer, but also you should note that $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is open for manipulation and is sometimes not even given, - I've noticed by more recent browser versions of FF and chrome, they don't even supply the server with an HTTP_REFERER value. This value should be treated as if it's a user inputed value (as it can be in some situations) that can also be empty, and given the caution and cleaning it deserves. Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the `HTTP_REFERER` is a full URL and not a file path. So you have to convert it to a path and strip some problematic characters. Something like this should do the trick:

```
// convert HTTP_REFERER from a URL to a path
$referer = str_replace('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
// replace all unwanted characters with underscores
$referer_folder = preg_replace('/[^\w\/]+/', '_', $referer);
// set the absolute dir path
$dir = __DIR__ . '/' . $referer_folder . '/gallery/';

if( !is_dir($dir) ) {
    mkdir($dir, 0750, true );
}
```